# How to tokenize a string in Lotus Notes Script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need to split a string into several tokens just like the java code below:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(mystring);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [Split(myString, " ")](http://www.codestore.net/help/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/2f21b5880854c04b85256c1c003fcf81?OpenDocument), where the first parameter is your string and the second one the token delimiter.

Here's the solution:

```
Dim myString = myDocument.myField(0)
Dim myTokens = Split(myString, " ")
Dim fisrtToken = myTokens(0)
Dim secondToken = myTokens(1)
```

Comment: dim index as integer
for index=lbound(myTokens) to ubound(myTokens)
  print myTokens(indeX)
end for

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I implemented from the answers around for IBM Lotus Notes 7:

```
Function isTokenInStr(tokenStr As String, strToSearch As String) As Boolean
    isTokenInStr = True

    Dim tokenArr As Variant
    tokenArr = Split(tokenStr, " ")
    Dim idxTokenArr As Integer 
    For idxTokenArr = LBound(tokenArr) To UBound(tokenArr) 
        Dim tokenElementStr As String
        tokenElementStr = tokenArr(idxTokenArr)
        If InStr(strToSearch, tokenElementStr) <= 0 Then
            isTokenInStr = False
            Exit For
        End If
    next
End Function
```